# How to return NULL or false value as false

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a problem want to check if column is null or false then it return 0 otherwise it returns 1, here my column is bit type. Below is my statement where I want to check:

```
   FROM    
   [dbo].[M_AttributeSet] AttributeSet   
    WHERE    
   (@AD_Org_ID IS NULL OR AttributeSet.AD_Org_ID IN (Select  ID From fnSplitter(@AD_Org_ID)))
    AND (@Atleastonevalue IS NULL OR  AttributeSet.Atleastonevalue =@Atleastonevalue )
```

How can I do this? Thanks for your comments in advance

Comment: Check which column? I can't immediately relate your question to your sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should return 0 when false or 0 and 1 when true:

```
ISNULL(yourcolumn,0)
```